# Entire drop-down menu quickly flashes upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a standard drop-down menu that uses jQuery to hide the children `li` elements.  However, upon loading the site, the child elements quickly appear and subsequently disappear (sort of like a quick flash).  I don't think this is at all related to the flash-of-unstyled-content known issue.

The site is in Hebrew, but that shouldn't affect anything. The site is located [here](http://medigo.co.il/?page_id=752)

If you'd like a sample HTML + CSS and the Javascript code, I would gladly post it here.

I was just wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before.  I'm seeing it in Chrome, and I haven't really checked if it also happens in IE and Firefox.

Thanks!

EDIT: HTML/CSS/JS shown below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">blah</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* NAVIGATION -- level 1 */
ul.menu { float: right; list-style-type: none; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 50px; }
ul.menu > li{ float: right; display: inline; position: relative; margin-left: 30px; }
ul.menu li > a { display: block; color: #5c5d5f; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: solid 1px #9b9a95;  }

ul.menu li:hover > a, ul.menu li a:hover , ul.menu li.current_page_item > a { color: black; }
body.home .current_page_item > a { }
body.home .current_page_item > a:hover { }

/* NAVIGATION -- level 2 */
ul.menu li > div { display: none; width: 157px; height: 171px; margin-right: -10px; position: absolute; opacity:0; background: url(images/subNav_bg.png) no-repeat top right; }

ul.menu li > div span { height: 15px; background: transparent; display: block; } /* used to push down the menu */
```

JS:

```
// navigation menu //
// add hasSubMenu to each li that has one //
$('.menu > li').has('ul').addClass('hasSubMenu');

// wrap with <div> //
$('li.hasSubMenu > ul').wrap('<div />');
$('ul.menu li > div').css('display', 'none');
$('ul.menu li > div').prepend('<span></span>');
$('li.hasSubMenu > a').click(function () {
    return false;
});

// add class to <div> for extendedBg //
$('li.extendedBg').find('div').addClass('subBg2');

$('li.hasSubMenu').hover(function () {
    // hover on
    $(this).addClass('hover').find('div').stop().fadeTo("medium", 1, /* when done fading */
        function () {
            $(this).find('div').css('display', 'block');
            //$(this).find('ul').css('display','block');
        }
    );

}, function () {
    // hover off
    $(this).removeClass('hover').find('div').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: please, post the sample html and css. Also jQuery or JS if you have one. It's working fine for me.

Comment: @chepe263: posted html, css, and jQuery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the dropdown menu as `display: none` in the page's CSS or directly in the element itself using `style="display:none"`. This will hide it as the page loads.

Comment: I don't thnk I can add the style="display:none" to the element itself, as this menu is dynamically generated through Wordpress' functions.  But I see what you mean, I'll add it to the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue :( except when i used the css to hide it on load, i now have the problem that it never displays! even when hovering over the parent...

Even before i posted my reply i thought id try one more thing

```
#navigation ul ul{
    display:none;
}
```

instead of

```
#navigation ul ul li{
    display:none;
}
```

and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I recommend setting the style to display:none the the li elements in a style sheet, so that the browser knows to render them initially as not displayed. Then, when jQuery loads, the inline style that jQuery adds will override the display style.

```
ul li {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.mobile-menu:not( .mm-menu ) {
     display: none;
}
```

where '.mobile-menu' is whatever class or ID you have given to the containing element of your menu.

e.g

```
<div class="mobile-menu">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
       <li><a href="/food">Food</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```